How to relate Matplotlib's fig.add_axes local coordinates with my coordinates?
Question
Motivated by this example form Matplotlib here I would like to make a similar one. I have run into following question: How can I relate the coordinates of the matplotlin graphics with my real world coordinates?
Example
To illustrate  it with the picture below:

I need the inset_axis rather precisely at the red points
I have tested left_inset_ax = fig.add_axes([1, 0, .05, .05], facecolor='k') for all four corners (see the black squares)
inside the colored area I can work with local coordinates (0..1, 0..1), but I do not find the relation to the outer coordinates
pherhaps I can set somewhere myCoordinates=True
I have also tried this example here, but I this is hand taylored, whereas I need an automated solution without hard coded figures.


I have different types of inset graphics. One of them is this below. They have been generated in a polar setting by

plt.plot( df_histo_cumsum.index,  df_histo_cumsum, c='k', lw=0.7) , or by
b = ax0.bar(np.deg2rad(self.wd_cc), Nbar[:,j], label=self.wd_cc,  color=self.ws_colors[j-1])

So they live in a different world of coordinates that is not easy to access for direct scaling.

Solutions and results

Some solutions as given here looks promising as long as the graphs are very simple. I took it as a base to add more features as title, x- and y labels, equidistant non-square settings, different numbers of grid points. The approach is

generate 2-dimensional data

select a few of them for  inset_axis

transform to local (0..1) coordinates in both directions

display the  inset_axis

use different number of grid points
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  def scaleXY(xgr,ygr,xT,yT): 
     xgr = (xgr-xT.min())/(xT.max()-xT.min())
     ygr = (ygr-yT.min())/(yT.max()-yT.min())
     return xgr, ygr

 nx, ny = 150, 60                                            # choose: number of data
 ix = np.linspace(-5, 20, nx)*100
 iy = np.linspace(-1, 15, ny)*100
 xq, yq = np.meshgrid(ix,iy, indexing='ij')                   # generate data
 dx, dy = 50, 30                                              # choose
 xp,yp = xq[::dx,::dy], yq[::dx,::dy]                         # select a few of them

 xgr, ygr = scaleXY(xp,yp,xq,yq)                              # scale them to (0..1)

 with plt.style.context('fast'): 
         fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) 
         ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

         ax1.scatter(xq,yq, s=5)                               # plot the base data
         ax1.scatter(xp,yp, c='lime', s=300, alpha = 0.6)      # plot the testing points

         ins = ax1.inset_axes([xgr[2,1], ygr[2,1],  0.2,0.2])  # check the inset positioning
         ins = ax1.inset_axes([xgr[1,1], ygr[1,1],  0.2,0.2])  # check the inset positioning
         ins = ax1.inset_axes([xgr[0,0], ygr[0,0],  0.2,0.2])  # check the inset positioning
         ins = ax1.inset_axes([xgr[2,0], ygr[2,0],  0.2,0.2])  # check the inset positioning

         ax1.set_aspect('equal')
         title = 'Even more dangerous area'
         ax1.set_title(title,fontweight='bold', fontsize=17)
         ax1.set_xlabel('x-direction', fontsize=17)
         ax1.set_ylabel('y-direction', fontsize=17)        

     plt.show() 



As results one can see that coordinates of the graphic separate from the coordinates of the user. This leads to the question:  How can I relate the coordinates of the matplotlin graphics with my real world coordinates?


I would appreciate any hints to other running solutions - thank you!

I'm not sure I quite follow your example, but you can tell inset_axes to use data coordinates by passing transform=ax.transData.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


target_x = [12, 12, 42, 42]
target_y = [7, 13, 13, 7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(target_x, target_y, color='lime')

x0 = target_x[0]
y0 = target_y[0]
width = target_x[2] - target_x[0]
height = target_y[2] - target_y[0]

ax_ins = ax.inset_axes([x0, y0, width, height], transform=ax.transData)

ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)

plt.show()


Since Matplotlib v3.6 inset_axes takes the projection and polar keywords, so you can create a polar plot as an inset that way.

GREAT - works - thank you! (and I have learned: MANDATORY: ax.set_xlim(--,--), ax.set_ylim(--,--) must be set too to make work ax.inset_axes right)

@pyano inset_axis should work fine without setting the limits.  However, for this example with nothing else in the main axes, if I don't set the limits then the inset nearly fills the main axes.  So I thought it was clearer this way.

As mentioned by @RuthC, since Matplotlib 3.6 the inset_axis function has some new features that are very helpful. For successful control, it is useful to note a few subtleties that can make life easier. I have listed some of them in the annotated code below.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#---- data generation
nx, ny = 15, 6
ix = np.linspace(-5, 20, nx)*10
iy = np.linspace(-1, 15, ny)*10
xo, yo  = np.meshgrid(ix,iy, indexing='ij')          # generated data as (x,y)-grid: blue dots
dx, dy = 4, 2
xs,ys = xo[::dx,::dy], yo[::dx,::dy]                 # some selected subset: green dots

Xtest = np.linspace(1, 20, 50)                       # some test data for...
Ytest = np.log(Xtest)                                # ... the inset-window


with plt.style.context('fast'): 

    #------ this is standard -------------------------
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) 
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    
    ax0.scatter(xo,yo, s=50, alpha=0.3)                          # blue dots
    ax0.scatter(xs,ys, c='lime', s=300, alpha = 0.6)             # green dots as target position for inset-windows
    
    title = 'A solution that can be automated'
    ax0.set_title(title,fontweight='bold', fontsize=17)
    ax0.set_xlabel('x-direction', fontsize=17)
    ax0.set_ylabel('y-direction', fontsize=17) 
            
    #------- here some subtleties with inset_axes
    ax0.set_xlim(xo.min(), xo.max())                              # this is mandatory despite...
    ax0.set_ylim(yo.min(), yo.max())                              # ... we have already  area-filling (xo,yo)-data
    ax0.set_aspect('equal')                                       # this makes life much easier for scaling the inset-windows

    
    DX, DY = 50, 50                                               # it is empirical what a good size for the inset_windows is
    bx12 = ax0.inset_axes([xs[1,2]-DX/2, ys[1,2]-DY/2,            # the position, centered to my target point 
                           DX,DY],                                # width (DX) and hight (DY) of the inset_windows
                          transform=ax0.transData)                # relates to the user coordinates (note the 'ax0')
    bx12.patch.set_alpha(0.0)                                     # makes the facecolor transparent
    bx12.set_title('Empty inset-window')
    
    bx11 = ax0.inset_axes([xs[1,1]-DX/2, ys[1,1]-DY/2,            # the position, centered to my target point 
                           DX,DY],                                
                          transform=ax0.transData)                
    bx11.patch.set_alpha(0.0) 
    bx11.plot(Xtest,Ytest,'yo-')
    bx11.set_title('Data on rectangular grid')

    
    bx21 = ax0.inset_axes([xs[2,1]-DX/2, ys[2,1]-DY/2,            # the position, centered to my target point 
                           DX,DY],                                
                          transform=ax0.transData,
                          projection='polar')                     # for polar coordinates
    bx21.patch.set_alpha(0) 
    bx21.plot(Xtest,Ytest,'yo-')
    bx21.set_title('Data on polar grid')
    
     
    bx32 = ax0.inset_axes([xs[3,2]-DX/2, ys[3,2]-DY/2,            # the position, centered to my target point 
                           DX,DY],                                
                          transform=ax0.transData,
                          projection='lambert')                   # for 2-dimensional projection on Earth grid
    bx32.patch.set_alpha(1) 
    bx32.set_facecolor('navy')                                    # background color navy-blue
    bx32.plot(Xtest,Ytest,'yo-')
    bx32.set_title('Data on Earth grid')  

    
    bx31 = ax0.inset_axes([xs[3,1]-DX/2, ys[3,1]-DY/2,            # the position, centered to my target point 
                           DX,DY],                                
                          transform=ax0.transData,
                          projection='rectilinear')                    
    bx31.patch.set_alpha(1)                                       # background color white
    zo = xo*yo
    bx31.pcolormesh(xo,yo,zo, edgecolors='w')
    bx31.contour(xo,yo,zo,cmap='plasma',linewidths=4)
    bx31.set_aspect('equal')                                      # adapts the size of the inset_window to the coordinates inside
    bx31.set_title("bx31.set_aspect('equal')")          
   
    plt.tight_layout()               
    plt.show()

